# PHP if Time or Date Greater than Show Echo

Tags: php, time, if-statement

This code does not want to compile. So I tried making the time text into a string.

```
$swnow = date('10:00:01');
$vsp=$swnow;
echo $vsp;

if ($vsp > '10:00:01') {echo 'greater than 10';}
```

I want an action if my server is visited at 10am.

Comment: how can `$vsp` be greater than `10:00:01` if that's what it's set to? Maybe I've understood it wrongly though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own solution to this, to avoid GMT response and server drain. Use JavaScript universal) v8 engine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

    //hours between 10am and 16pm
    if (hours>10){
        if (hours<16){
            document.write("phone anim");
        }else{
            document.write("phone static")
        }
    }

//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Ironically. My own code is not evening working. PHP or JavaScript no time works!

Comment: My code IS working now, the best solution for this fix is to use 16, 16.00, 04.00, 4.00 so it covers ALL combinations of 4 o clock!

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna work with real time use this but I will much more consider working with UNIX_TIMESTAMP :

```
$Date = date('H', strtotime('10:00:01'));
if($Date > 10){
    echo 'Well, 11, 12, 13, 14 ... till 23';
} else {
    echo 'Maybe it is 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09 or 10 hours AM.';
}
```

Comment: I have used strtotime(); in this but it does not work. I updated your post.

Comment: OK maybe my code might not be working because in GMT it is not even 10!

Comment: OK if ($Date < '10:00:01') {echo ' <br /><br />less than 10';} does not work too!

Comment: Can it check for 10:00:01 and also 16:00:01 and 10:00 and 10 at same time?

Comment: Yes, create a new variable and test it with $Date > 10 OR $NewVar < 16 .. I don't know what you wanna do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime()` function to convert string to time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$Date = date('H:i:s');
if($Date > '10:00:01'){
    echo 'less than 10';
} else {
    echo 'bla-bla-bla';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have like this, then you can use :

```
if ( $mydate > strtotime('2013-03-19 17:14:40') ){
echo 'Hello';
}
```